# Caret position misplaced in phonegap

Tags: cordova, scroll, focus

I've built a phonegap app. As per default when you click an input field the page scrolls (iPhone keyboard comes up). My problem is that sometimes the caret can't keep up, so it gets misplaced (above the actual input field). I'm ok with the scrolling part, but I would like the caret to be positioned correctly. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('newTitleInput').value = ' ';
    document.getElementById('newTitleInput').value = '';
}, 100);
```